# Calling the File.ReadAllBytes method in F#

Tags: f#

Here is a sample of my code:

```
let getAllBooks bookDirectory =
    seq {yield! Directory.GetFiles(bookDirectory)}
    |> Seq.map (fun eachFile -> eachFile.ReadAllBytes)
```

It fails to work. What is wrong? What should I write instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like you said in the title, the function is called `File.ReadAllBytes` ;)

It is a static method of the `System.IO.File` class, and therefore has to be called on the `File` type, not some instance:

```
open System.IO

let getAllBooks bookDirectory =
    seq {yield! Directory.GetFiles (bookDirectory) }
    |> Seq.map (fun eachFile -> File.ReadAllBytes eachFile)
```

Btw, this code could be improved, since the result of `GetFiles` is an array, which is also a `seq`:

```
open System.IO

let getAllBooks bookDirectory =
    Directory.GetFiles bookDirectory
    |> Seq.map (fun eachFile -> File.ReadAllBytes eachFile)
```

Furthermore, you could simply pass the `ReadAllBytes` function directly to map:

```
open System.IO

let getAllBooks bookDirectory =
    Directory.GetFiles bookDirectory
    |> Seq.map File.ReadAllBytes
```

Finally, you can get rid of the function parameter as well, if you like:

```
open System.IO

let getAllBooks =
    Directory.GetFiles
    >> Seq.map File.ReadAllBytes
```

---

Update for the comment:

> I have an additional question: How may I convert a byte array into its numeric equivalent?

You may use the static methods in the `System.BitConverter` class, for example `System.BitConverter.ToInt32`:

```
open System

let array = [| 0x00uy; 0x10uy; 0x00uy; 0x00uy |]

BitConverter.ToInt32 (array, 0)
|> printfn "Array as Int32: %d"
// Prints: Array as Int32: 4096
```

Don't overlook the `ToString` method in there, which can convert a byte array to a hex string:

```
BitConverter.ToString array
|> printfn "%s"
// Prints: 00-10-00-00
```

All available conversion methods can be found [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the very lucid explanation! I apologise if my question came across as silly -- I am new to programming, and this is my first time working with a .NET language.

I have an additional question: How may I convert a byte array into its numeric equivalent? Thanks in advance for your help. :-)

Comment: @MY_G, no problem. Your question was clear and concise, definitely not at all silly. :)

Comment: @MY_G, I updated the answer for the question in your comment.